WSL host system doesn't support vsock: stat /dev/vhost-vsock: no such file or directory
Trying to use kata container from WSL. System supports nested virtualization.

But when I tried to check with command kata-runtime kata-check got below error
ERRO[0000] /opt/kata/share/defaults/kata-containers/configuration-qemu.toml: host system doesn't support vsock: stat /dev/vhost-vsock: no such file or directory  arch=amd64 name=kata-runtime pid=11438 source=runtime
/opt/kata/share/defaults/kata-containers/configuration-qemu.toml: host system doesn't support vsock: stat /dev/vhost-vsock: no such file or directory

Is this some issue with WSL or I have to perform some step to enable it?
